# Is $f(x) \leq x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ when sine series $f(x)$ are used to approximate $x$ based on derivatives at $x=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, interpolation, trigonometric-series

This is a simpler "cousin" question to [Would sine trigonometric series $f(x)$ for approximating $g(x) = x$ always be $f(x) \leq x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066141/would-sine-trigonometric-series-fx-for-approximating-gx-x-always-be-f) . I am asking this as a separate question, since this may be relatively easier to answer than the linked question.

I am trying to use set of $c_k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{M} c_k \sin kx \approx x$.

$c_k$ is determined by setting
$$f^{(2k+1)}(0) =0,\,\, k=1,..,M-1$$
$$f'(0) =1$$

These conditions provide $M$ linear equations to solve for $c_k$.

Question is, is it guaranteed that $f(x) \leq x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ for any $M\geq 2$?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of your system is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&\cdots&1\\
1&2^3&2^5&\cdots&2^{2M-1}\\
1&3^3&3^5&\cdots&2^{2M-1}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
1&M^3&M^5&\cdots&M^{2M-1}.
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is not hard to check that this determinant is never zero, so your system has unique solution. That means that $c_1=1$, $c_2=\cdots=c_M=0$ is the only solution, and thus
$$
f(x)=\sin x
$$
for all $M$.